# trouble finding/installing cpu driver for AMD FX 8350

Tags: drivers, 13.10, amd-processor, cpufreq

I'm very much new to Linux, but I've hunted for days and can not find any solution to my problem. I'm trying to use cpufreq to control the throttle on my cpu (AMD FX-8350, 64-bit), but I apparently do not have drivers for the cpu:

```
galaxy@MilkyWay:/$ cpufreq-info
cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 1:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 2:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 3:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
```

I think the drivers I have available to try are:

```
galaxy@MilkyWay:/$ ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/cpufreq/
amd_freq_sensitivity.ko  p4-clockmod.ko  speedstep-lib.ko
```

But modprobe can't see them?:

```
galaxy@MilkyWay:/lib/modules/3.11.0-18-generic/kernel/drivers/cpufreq$ sudo modprobe amd_freq_sensitivity.ko
FATAL: Module amd_freq_sensitivity.ko not found.
```

The same thing happens with any of the three. I've tried some various other tweaks on modprobe and every time I get a FATAL. I must being making some silly mistake. Are these even the right drivers? Help!

EDIT: I don't know if this matters, but I have Ubuntu running inside a VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does matter if you run [cpufrequtils](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cpufrequtils) [image: Install cpufrequtils] on a virtual machine *vs.* on bare metal.

Virtual Box and other virtualization software will use the real CPU but not all features of the host CPU are exposed to the guest.

Controlling the CPU frequency is one of the CPU feature that is not available in a virtual machine created with Virtual Box. CPU settings you make from the host OS will likely be respected in the guest.

Comment: Hmm interesting. So I've been trying to do something that's impossible on a VirtualBox. I wonder why that limitation is so difficult to find documented online. Regardless, thank you.

Comment: But ok, aside from the CPU throttling, I believe I do need a driver so some other softwares can read the CPU. Are you saying that being in a virtualbox makes interfacing with the cpu impossible? Can I not install any driver?

Comment: Yeah, there is however a feature from VBox to define an execution cap for the CPU cores used by the VM.

Comment: I'm marking this as answered, because, while I now understand I cannot throttle from the VBox, I still need to find a driver, which the question was largely about.